# "only so often" meaning?

Tags: idioms

> The Golden State Warriors are in the midst of one of those charmed NBA seasons that happen **only so often**. 
>   (from a [WSJ article](http://www.wsj.com/articles/golden-state-the-team-that-eats-together-1423682960?mod=trending_now_1))

I cannot find the meaning of "only so often" here. Is this a idiom or should I separate, like only, so often??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Only so often* is an idiom.

It means *sometimes* or *occasionally* with a slight emphasis on it being a rare occasion.

It is similar to *every so often*, which also means *sometimes* or *occasionally* but with a general feeling of being more common.

If I get my hair cut every three months, I might say:

> Every so often I get my hair cut.

If my husband only shaves once every two years, I might say:

> It's only so often I get to see my husband without a beard.